# spring boot commandline runner is using windows default character encoding

Tags: spring-boot, utf-8, character-encoding

I am running spring boot application on windows and its using windows-1252 encoding. However stand alone java program is using UTF-8 encodeing. How do I force spring boot to use UTF-8. below code outputs ????. I use the below command using jar -jar target\spring-boot-example.jar

I verified that in power shell program that default character set is windows-1252 (System.Text.Encoding)::Default

```
public class SpringBootConsoleApplication implements CommandLineRunner {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication.run(SpringBootConsoleApplication.class, args);
}

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Default Charset=" +   Charset.defaultCharset());
        System.out.println("test::" +"الرياض");        
    }
}
```

I tried the below options in application.properties without success:

```
# Charset of HTTP requests and responses. Added to the "Content-Type"    header if not set explicitly.
 spring.http.encoding.charset=UTF-8
 # Enable http encoding support.
 spring.http.encoding.enabled=true
 # Force the encoding to the configured charset on HTTP requests and   responses.
 spring.http.encoding.force=true
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [spring boot application showing ??? characters instead of unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44992808/spring-boot-application-showing-characters-instead-of-unicode)

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: This works on Windows under Eclipse and its console as long as you save the source file with UTF-8 encoding. If you try to save as 1252 then Eclipse will warn you that it's not going to work. I'd like to see a hex dump of the relevant part of your source file on Windows. I suspect it's not saved on disk as UTF-8. If it is OK on disk then the probable cause is that your Windows console is not capable of rendering UTF-8.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

@AbjitSarkar @JC Carrillo this issue seems to be with windows environment. I deployed the same code on UbuntuVM and everything seems to be fine.

Thank you for listening to me and giving me tips to explore !!

Answer (score 4):

Try running your app with `-Dfile.encoding=UTF8` in the command line.

Example:

`java -jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 target/myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Comment: tried on command line, Default Charset: UTF-8 is printed but the characters are still printed as ???

Comment: It helped, thank you! When running SpringBoot as a runnable jar, it was writing in Win-1252, but this options both logs and generated files are now in UTF-8. Great!

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be your stdout, not the code. I suggest you create a simple `main` class, without Spring Boot, or any external dependencies, and print UTF-8 characters. I'm on a Mac, and the following code prints find for me:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Default Charset=" + Charset.defaultCharset());
        System.out.println("test::" + "الرياض");
    }
}

Default Charset=UTF-8
test::الرياض
```

Another thing you may want to try is writing it to a file instead of stdout.

**Edit**:

I think you're barking the wrong tree. No one uses Spring Boot for printing to stdout. The `spring.http.encoding` properties you'd set are actually [HttpEncodingProperties](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/http/HttpEncodingProperties.java) which Boot uses to auto configure encoding using [HttpEncodingAutoConfiguration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/HttpEncodingAutoConfiguration.java). But all that's for a HTTP request, not for printing to stdout. Any application that deserves to go to Prod should use a logger, and not `System.out.println`.

Comment: @JC Carrillo public static main prints correct unicode. 

java "-Dfile.encoding=UTF8" -jar target\my-app.jar prints below

Default charset=UTF-8
test: ????
not sure which setting is causing it to print this way :(
Below is the maven project, I am running this on windows 7:
https://github.com/AyubOpen/spring-boot-jdbc.git

Comment: Main class works, however the spring boot project does not, puzzling..pulling my hair :)

Comment: This seems to be a windows issue, tried on ubuntu everything works. Have to figure out how to pass the correct encoding when running on windows

Comment: @Ayub there's nothing to pass. Like I said in my edit, printing to stdout is not a real use case

Comment: you are right printing std out is not real use case, this I was just debugging. 2The jdbc datasource I tried using debug, When I step through the debugger, I could see that just before printing when I evaluate the expression the unicode is correctly retrieved from the database. Its printing ??? only in sys out.Also print works without issues on ubuntu